# Install postgresclient/sqlserver odbc drivers in dockerfile

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, driver, pyodbc

I'm trying to install postgres odbc driver to connect with different external databases with pyodbc

My app receives credentials from any database of type `mysql`, `sqlserver`, `postgresql`, etc. And I'm having problems installing the drivers.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.10.9-bullseye
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jdk

#Mysql driver
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list \
        > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        locales \
        apt-transport-https \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install unixodbc-dev libodbc1\
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install msodbcsql18

RUN sed -i -E 's/(CipherString\s*=\s*DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=)2/\11/' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl gcc g++ gnupg unixodbc-dev


#Postgresql
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit libsasl2-modules

#Postgresql unicode
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql
RUN apt-get install -y odbc-postgresql


COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run", "--debugger", "--reload", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

When I try to connecto with postgres database I got the error:

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC]could not
> connect to server: No such file or directory\n\tIs the server running
> locally and accepting\n\tconnections on Unix domain socket
> "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?\n (101) (SQLDriverConnect)')

When I connect with sql server database, I can extract info, but when I try to send info to the database I got this error:

> TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746

I'm trying to set the openSSL to 1.0, and that allow me to extract info from sql servers database, but no send it with postgres, even the psql console is not installed :c

I'm having struggling with this drivers for some days. If anyone can help me, I'll be very greatful

Comment: Does `apt-get install -y postgresql` really install, initialize and start a Postgres service?

Comment: I've edited the question to remove what looks like valid AWS credentials.  It's possible an indexer has already picked them up and they're still present in the edit history.  Please invalidate these credentials immediately, lest an unsavory actor use them to do things in AWS on your dime.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to reduce it to a [mcve]?  If it's specifically about PostgreSQL, do you need the MySQL and MSSQL drivers, for example?  Where is the database running and how have you configured its location in your application?

Comment: No, it seems that postgres service is not being installed